# Repetir un proceso con ARRAY

Tags: funciones, function, función-personalizada, postgis

Estoy preparando una función para PgRouting que se basa en otra función que también he preparado yo. 
El fin de esto es hacer una función que introduciendo las coordenadas de origen y destino de como respuesta una ruta. 
He conseguido que sea de punto a punto con pgr_dijkstra. 
Ahora necesito hacer lo mismo, pero con pgr_dijkstravia. Esta se basa en un ARRAY, obligas a la ruta a pasar por unos puntos específicos que tu le introduces. Una especie a Google maps, que puedes poner los puntos que quieras y la ruta te la hace tirando por esos puntos que tu le has impuesto.
La primera función con ARRAY la he conseguido sacar y sería así:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wrk3_dijkstravia( 
IN edges_subset regclass, 
IN via_vertices ANYARRAY,
OUT seq INTEGER, 
OUT path_id integer,
OUT path_seq integer,
OUT start_vid BIGINT,
OUT end_vid BIGINT,
OUT node BIGINT,
OUT edge BIGINT,
OUT name TEXT, 
OUT cost FLOAT, 
OUT agg_cost FLOAT,
OUT azimuth FLOAT,
OUT route_agg_cost FLOAT,
OUT route_readable TEXT, 
OUT route_geom geometry ) 
RETURNS SETOF record 
AS 
$BODY$ 
WITH dijkstra AS 
    (SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstravia( 'SELECT gid as id, reverse_cost, * FROM ' || $1,
    $2::BIGINT[], true ,false)), 
get_geom AS
    (SELECT dijkstra.*, ways.name,
    CASE WHEN dijkstra.node = ways.source THEN the_geom ELSE ST_Reverse(the_geom) 
    END 
    AS route_geom FROM dijkstra LEFT JOIN ways ON (edge = gid) ORDER BY seq) 
SELECT 
seq,
path_id,
path_seq,
start_vid,
end_vid,
node,
edge,
name, 
cost,
agg_cost, 
route_agg_cost, 
degrees(ST_azimuth(ST_StartPoint(route_geom), 
ST_EndPoint(route_geom))) AS azimuth, 
ST_Astext(route_geom),
route_geom
FROM get_geom ORDER BY seq; 
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

Y un ejemplo de consulta a una vista que ya he creado sería esta:

```
select * from wrk3_dijkstravia('vehiculo_tiempo', ARRAY [42, 64, 85])
```

Y me devuelve la ruta. Pero las variables del ARRAY son ids de los nodos y con visión a que sea utilizada por un cliente no es viable.
Entonces aquí viene la siguiente función, que se basa en esta primera:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wrk1_fromAtoB(
    IN edges_subset regclass,
    IN x ANYARRAY, IN y ANYARRAY,
    OUT seq INTEGER,
    OUT gid BIGINT,
OUT name TEXT,
OUT distancia_m NUMERIC,
OUT distancia_total NUMERIC, 
OUT cost NUMERIC, 
OUT agg_cost NUMERIC,
OUT azimuth FLOAT,
OUT route_agg_cost NUMERIC,
OUT route_readable TEXT, 
OUT route_geom geometry )

RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    final_query TEXT;
BEGIN

    final_query :=
        FORMAT( $$
            WITH
            vertices AS (
                SELECT * FROM ways_vertices_pgr
                WHERE id IN (
                    SELECT source FROM %1$I
                    UNION
                    SELECT target FROM %1$I)
            ),
            dijkstra AS (
                SELECT *
                FROM wrk3_dijkstravia(
                    '%1$I',
                    ARRAY[(SELECT id FROM vertices 
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(%2$s, %3$s), 4258) LIMIT 1)]
            ))
            SELECT
                seq,
                gid,
                dijkstra.name,
                TRUNC (ways.length_m::numeric) AS distancia_m,
                TRUNC (sum(length_m::numeric) OVER (ORDER BY seq), 2) as distancia_total,
                ROUND (dijkstra.cost::numeric, 2) AS cost,
                ROUND (dijkstra.agg_cost::numeric, 2) as agg_cost,
                azimuth,
                route_agg_cost::NUMERIC,
                route_readable,
                route_geom AS geom
            FROM dijkstra LEFT JOIN ways ON dijkstra.edge = ways.gid;$$,
        edges_subset, x,y);
    RAISE notice '%', final_query;
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE final_query;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Y la consulta sería esta:

```
select * from wrk1_fromAtoB('vehiculo_distancia',  ARRAY[-7.559516429901122,   -7.561619281768799, -7.563893795013428], ARRAY [ 43.01592861164031, 43.01329278981061, 43.00988801917453])
```

Pero el error que me da es el siguiente:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 15: ...        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point({-7.559516...
```

Esto es porque en el ST_Point me está metiendo todas las coordenadas:

```
dijkstra AS (
                SELECT *
                FROM wrk3_dijkstravia(
                    'vehiculo_distancia',
                    ARRAY[(SELECT id FROM vertices 
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point({-7.559516429901122,-7.561619281768799,-7.563893795013428}, {43.01592861164031,43.01329278981061,43.00988801917453}), 4258) LIMIT 1)]
```

Lo que necesito es que haga el ST_Point con cada "x" e "y" y no con todas las x e y. 
Pero no se muy bien como hacer esto. 
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Alguien podría echarme una mano? u orientarme un poco, porque no se muy bien como hacerlo.
Estoy mirando formas con LOOP, pero sigo sin sacarlo. Gracias¡

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido avanzar un poco en mi función:

```
DO 
$do$
DECLARE 
    x numeric[];
    arr numeric[] := ARRAY [[-7.563947439193725, 43.02141169991877], [-7.56184458732605, 43.01576387609036],[-7.5599563121795645, 43.006741968861974]];
BEGIN

    FOREACH x SLICE 1 IN ARRAY arr
    LOOP 
         RAISE notice  'WITH
            vertices AS (
                SELECT * FROM ways_vertices_pgr
                WHERE id IN (
                    SELECT source FROM ways
                    UNION
                    SELECT target FROM ways)
            ),
            dijkstra AS (
                SELECT *
                FROM wrk3_dijkstravia(
                    ways,

                   ARRAY[(SELECT id FROM vertices
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(%,%), 4258) LIMIT 1)]
            ))' ,x[1], x[2];
        END LOOP;
END;
$do$
```

Pero con esto solo consigo que me lo haga en el raise. Quisiera que me ejecutara esa función.
A ver si alguien me puede orientar. 
Gracias.